# Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR while running `grunt`

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm new to the Grunt world.

After installing grunt-cli, and all the dependencies, here is my : `Gruntfile.js`

```
/*
        Grunt installation:
        -------------------
            npm install -g grunt-cli
            npm install -g grunt-init
            npm init (creates a `package.json` file)

        Project Dependencies:
        ---------------------
            npm install grunt --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-concat --save-dev
            npm install grunt-contrib-watch --save-dev



        Example Usage:
        --------------
            grunt -v
            grunt release -v

*/


module.exports = function(grunt) {
    "use strict";

    grunt.initConfig({

        concat: {

            js: {
                src: ['js/bootstrap.min.js', 'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'],
                dest: 'build/js/scripts.js'
            },

            css: {
                src: ['css/bootstrap.min.css', 'css/font-awesome.min.css'],
                dest: 'build/css/styles.css'
            }
        },

        watch: {

            js: {
                files: ['js/**/*.js'],
                task: ['concat:js']
            },

            css: {
                files: ['css/**/*.css'],
                task: ['concat:css']
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasksNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'watch']);

};
```

---

## Result

Now the testing part, I tried run `grunt`, I kept getting :

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError: undefined is not a function
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

---

Can someone please tell me what did I do wrong here ?

Comment: It doesn't understand `grunt.loadNpmTasksNpmTasks`. It should be `grunt.loadNpmTasks` like the previous one. I think it's just confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `default` target is not being created properly due to a typo. Try renaming

```
grunt.loadNpmTasksNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```

to

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
```

Comment: Any diff between them ?

Comment: The first isn't a valid grunt method.

Comment: Quick question, I seem to be halting say `Running Watch task Waiting ...`

Comment: `grunt-contrib-watch` is meant to do that, it's saying that the program is waiting, listening (watching) for changes.

Comment: IS there a way to configure my grunt watch to do nothing if nothing has been change ?

Comment: If you want your browser to update when you change a css or js file, leave it up. It won't do anything if nothing has changed. I'm not sure what your question is really.

Comment: That is how watch works, the program needs to be running constantly in order to listen for changes in order to propagate them.

Answer (score 1):

Have faced similar issues and tried below command where your node modules is installed which resolved issue for me:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```